# ImageButton inside Android ListView with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I have implemented a BaseAdapter and binded that BaseAdapter to my ListView. The Layout for each row of the ListView contains an ImageButton. How do i bind that ImageButton to a click listener and then use that ImageButton to call a new activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a sample adapter class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.amazon.mp3.AlbumDetail.Details;



public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private  ArrayList<Details> allElementDetails;
private Context con; 
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
String temp;
public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Details> results) {
    allElementDetails = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    con=context;
}
public int getCount() {
    return allElementDetails.size();        
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return allElementDetails.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
                    //select ur xml file
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_elements, null);

    TextView textview1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    TextView textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
    Button buy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_song_button);
    buy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent=new   Intent(con,Buy_song.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

         con.startActivity(intent);


        }
            else
                Toast.makeText(con,"Not available for purchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    if(allElementDetails.get(position).songname.contains("&amp;"))
    {
  temp=allElementDetails.get(position).songname.replace("&amp;", "and");
    textview1.setText(temp);
    }
    else
    textview1.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).songname);

    textview2.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).runtime);
    if(allElementDetails.get(position).price.startsWith("$"))
    textview3.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).price);
    else
           textview3.setText("Album only");
    return convertView;
}    

}
```

Look for the buy button in this adapter.